# Welches Genus hat ein zitiertes Wort?

Tags: gender, quotes

Wie kann man das Genus von einem Wort oder Zitat wissen? Wie kann ich zum Beispiel herausfinden, welche Artikel ich in folgenden Texten für die Zitierten Wörter verwenden muss:

> „Das wage ich nicht zu probieren“ — Was für eine Wortart ist **dieser/dieses/diese** „zu“?
>
> Ist im Wort „Seejungfrau“ **der/das/die** „See“ männlich oder weiblich?

Was für ein Genus verwendet man hier? Das heißt, sagt man in diesen Beispielen „dieser „zu““, „dieses „zu““ oder „diese „zu““, und dieser „der „See““, „das „See““ oder „die „See““?

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht ganz, wie der Titel der Frage zu verstehen ist. Im Text fragst du nach einzelnen Wörtern. Könntest du das bitte noch mal klären? Danke!

Comment: @splattne: I'm trying to distinguish between mentioning a word ("ich schwimme in der See") and quoting the word ("ich habe „See“ gesagt"). I want to apply an article in the latter case, and would like to know which gender the article should have. Saying that it should be the same as the actual word would cause problems for words such as "zu", which have no gender, and "Meer", which have several.

Comment: Okay, now it's clear.

Comment: Das Wort - deswegen: dieses/das "zu". Man sagt eigentlich Meerjungfrau und nicht Seejungfrau. Und das Geschlecht richtet sich nach den Hauptbestandteil Frau.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

„zu“ ist in diesem Fall eine Konjunktion (es gibt „zu“ ja auch als Präposition und in anderen Funktionen).

Seejungfrau: kommt drauf an – wenn das Wort als Synonym zu Meerjungfrau genutzt wird, ist „See“ weiblich, „die See“ als Synonym zu „das Meer“. Aber die Mythologie besetzt ja auch Quellen und (Binnen-)Seen mit solchem weiblichen Personal. Ist demnach ein bestimmter (Binnen-)See gemeint, wäre es „der See“. **Wichtig**: Das Genus des Gesamtwortes **ändert sich aber nicht**: Es richtet sich immer nachdem Hauptbegriff, egal ob „das Meer“, „die See“ oder „der See“ voransteht. Also: „**die** Seejungfrau“, unabhängig vom grammatikalischen Genus des Sees. „Der Wassermann“ bleibt ja auch *Maskulinum*, auch wenn „das Wasser“ *Neutrum* ist.

**Edit:** Das Zitat selber hat m. E. kein einheitliches Genus. Das Genus hängt vielmehr davon ab, **was** zitiert wird: ein Wort (dann *Neutrum*), ein Satz (dann *Maskulinum*), eine Passage (dann *Femininum*). Generell ist man auf der sicheren Seite, wenn man formuliert:

> „Welche Wortart ist **das Wort** ‚zu‘ in ‚Ich wage nicht, zu …‘?“
>
> „Welches Genus hat **das Wort ‚See‘** in ‚Seejungfrau‘?“

Analog dazu kann man *teilweise* auch verkürzt formulieren:

> „Welche Wortart ist **das** ‚zu‘ in ‚Ich wage nicht, zu …‘?“

Im ersten Beispiel geht das, weil „zu“ kein Substantiv ist und daher kein grammatikalisches Geschlecht hat. Im zweiten Beispiel geht das aus demselben Grund nicht: Das Wort „See“ hat ein grammatisches Geschlecht, das gerade nicht Neutrum ist. Daher würde es seltsam klingen, zu fragen:

> „Welches Genus hat **das ‚See‘** in ‚Seejungfrau‘?“

Hier würde ich auf jeden Fall vollständig formulieren und von „dem Wort ‚See‘“ sprechen.

Comment: Entschuldigung, ich glaube, dass meine Frage undeutlich war. Ich habe sie jetzt erklärt. Diese Fragen waren nur Beispiele, damit ich meine richtige Frage darstellen konnte, nämlich was für ein Genus ein _Zitat_ hat.

Comment: @Tim N - ok, habe soeben versucht, meine Antwort entsprechend zu erweitern.

Comment: @Tim N - noch ein edit meinerseits, jetzt ist hoffentlich  "Version 1.0" erreicht :)

Comment: Note that leaving out "Wort" doesn't always work. It would not work in "Ich habe „See“ gesagt". The usual way is to leave out the article anyway. "Was für eine Wortart ist „zu“?" - "Ist im Wort „Seejungfrau“ „See“ männlich oder weiblich?". (Here it would actually better to put another "das Wort" or "der Wortteil" in, as two quotes follow each other) The disctinction is made by different stressing/emphasizing.